# Passing variable to getElementById results in NaN error

Tags: javascript

```
function upgrade(cost, hps, htmlName, id)
{
    /* calc new cost based on quantity currently has */
    var currUpgradeCost = Math.floor(cost * Math.pow(1.1,upgradeCount[id]));

    /* can they afford it? */
    if(totalHacks >= currUpgradeCost)
    {
        /* tally up THIS UPGRADE */
        upgradeCount[id]++;
        /* total the upgrades as a whole */
        totalUpgrades = totalUpgrades + hps;
        /* subtract this cost fro the total hacks so far */
        totalHacks = totalHacks - currUpgradeCost; 
        /* update the HTML */
        document.getElementById('hpc').innerHTML = totalUpgrades.toFixed(1); 
        document.getElementById('totalHacks').innerHTML = totalHacks.toFixed(0); 
    };

    /* calc/display cost for next upgrade */
    var nextCost = Math.floor(cost * Math.pow(1.1,upgradeCount[id])); 
    document.getElementById(htmlName).innerHTML = nextCost; 

};

 <button onclick="upgrade(15, .1,'upgradePCCost', 0)">Upgrade System</button>
            - Cost <span id="upgradePCCost">15</span><br/>

            <button onclick="upgrade(100, .5,'scriptBotCost', 1)">Script Bot</button>
            - Cost <span id="scriptBotCost">100</span><br/>
```

EDIT: FULL FUNCTION:(yes tinkering with a clicker game to learn JS. )And I'll take the negative votes if it will solve it. These are the two sections giving me issues.
/EDIT
OK, hope I made this simple and to the point. Main problem - it works, it just gives a `NaN` error for the `targetId`.

Now I've been reading everywhere, and a couple things I found.

1. I could not find anyone passing a var to the `elementById` in the manner I was.
2. Since I cannot find the answer that works - I am obviously doing it wrong.

This is all part a larget project, and to avoid redundant code, it is based on what button they are clicking, so I just add that to the function. The only line that does not work, is the one above: `elementById`. My debugger does not show any errors, the html just keeps spitting out a `NaN` instead of `444` (in this example)

Many of the sites / forums I checked, all say this should work. So there is something I am missing.

Couple of the things I've tried:

-`.toString()`
-`elementsByName`

Thanks. I am pretty sure I checked everywhere on S.O. to make sure this is not a dupe, as no one is doing the same thing with the same results (i.e. many I found were solved because of typos - obviously, that is not my issue)

Comment: Your leaving out something in your code.  Which line exactly is throwing the error?  When I try your code it works.

Comment: I get no such result when I run that code. The problem has to be something to do with the missing code (which was originally represented by `..........` in your question but which I removed when I converted your code to be a live demo).

Comment: Also the snippet works just fine.

Comment: It works for me too. Are you sure you're not making some operation with the string? Like adding or subtracting another string.

Comment: So it works. I didn't get the problem. You mentioned an error but there isn't one.

Comment: The snippet is also working for me. 999 gets replaced by 444 as expected.

Comment: this works fine for me.

Comment: The only I can suggest is highlight the parameter name, copy and paste into the find function to make sure you haven't mis-spelled it.

Comment: Try forcing someVar to be a string. `= (someVar + "") `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this code doesn't work for you, definitely related with other part of your code. document.getElementById function expects string as argument, and you pass one, so, i don't think it's the problem. Similarly, you assign string to innerHTML property takes also string, but passing number value doesn't hurt, because javascript converts it to string for you. So, the error you get NaN (not a number) has nothing to do with the line:

```
document.getElementById(htmlName).innerHTML = someVar;
```

I don't see the other part of your code as you trimmed out, but I suspect the function runs when you click on the button, is reading the value "444" in your example, and passing to your "myFunction". Probably you should look for error there.

Ask yourself the classical debugger question when you stuck, what justifies my expectation the things to be as the way I expected? And find the line in your code justifies your expectation and check if it runs the way it should?

Using your example, you pass a "number" to innerHTML property, any you get NaN error. So, the question is, what justifies that the number you pass is a number? And find that part of your code, if you pass a number.

UPDATE: After seeing other part of your code, it looks your nextCost variable is NaN, so you cannot assign it to innerHTML.

nextCost is using some math calculation, which involves cost, which is number, considering onClick calls, only thing remains is the upgradeCount[id] array/object, both can be, but probably array. So I think you should look still other part of your code, which forms upgradeCount array, and make sure that upgradeCount in index id has number value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Ahet, thanks for the tip. I write lots of languages and sometimes they get crossed (which I believe happened here). So while I think it looks correct, there is prob a small typo somewhere, please look again at the original post with the missing code and see if you see it there. From batch to pascal to vb, php/mysql I comment a lot, so hope there is no confusion as to what the code does - ty again!

Comment: Cain, I just updated my answer, please check if it's helpful.

Comment: upgradeCount = new Array(30), it will tally each of the 30 upgrades. (originally it was at upgradeCount = new Array(),but neither make a difference.

Comment: that's fine, but when you create a new array the way you do, all elements of that array will be initially undefined. Therefore, without initializing them to a number value, in your example, upgradeCount[0] = 0, and upgradeCount[1] = 0 for example, when you pass it to Math.pow function, it will produce NaN. Can you check before calling nextCost = Math.floor (...) upgradeCount[0] and upgradeCount[1] holds a number value?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me:

```html
<button onclick="upgrade(15, .1,'upgradePCCost', 0)">Upgrade System</button>
- Cost <span id="upgradePCCost">15</span><br/>

<button onclick="upgrade(100, .5,'scriptBotCost', 1)">Script Bot</button>
- Cost <span id="scriptBotCost">100</span><br/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function upgrade(cost, hps, htmlName, id)
{
 upgradeCount = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
 totalHacks = 0;
    /* calc new cost based on quantity currently has */
    var currUpgradeCost = Math.floor(cost * Math.pow(1.1,upgradeCount[id]));

    /* can they afford it? */
    if(totalHacks >= currUpgradeCost)
    {
        /* tally up THIS UPGRADE */
        upgradeCount[id]++;
        /* total the upgrades as a whole */
        totalUpgrades = totalUpgrades + hps;
        /* subtract this cost fro the total hacks so far */
        totalHacks = totalHacks - currUpgradeCost; 
        /* update the HTML */
        document.getElementById('hpc').innerHTML = totalUpgrades.toFixed(1); 
        document.getElementById('totalHacks').innerHTML = totalHacks.toFixed(0); 
    };

    /* calc/display cost for next upgrade */
    var nextCost = Math.floor(cost * Math.pow(1.1,upgradeCount[id])); 
    document.getElementById(htmlName).innerHTML = nextCost; 

};
</script>
```

I've run your code, and as you can see. If all the values are correct this function should work. As you can see i added upgradeCount and totalHacks so i could make the code run. But remember, before you can do math on the array you must be sure that all the values in it, is numbers, else you will get NaN.

Comment: Redid original post with full function and the two lines that are giving the nan error BTW TYVM!! FOR THE LIGHTNING FAST RESPONSES. WOW.

Comment: @Cain What's in upgradeCount??

Comment: there are 30 upgrades (or more - just playin with it) - the array will tally each one for cost purposes

Comment: @Cain You can't just do = new Array(30), you must either fill in the values, as i did in my example, or .push all the values into the array variable.

Comment: That works,[code]var upgradeCount = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];[/code] Most of the languages I work with, you can just initialize an empy array, or not at all (php ), 2nd set of eyes always works - thanks!!!

Comment: @Cain No problem man. Javascript, what more to say. And btw. You are calculating the same price twice if you didn't notice? currUpgradeCost and nextCost will always be the same number ^^